# TableToTable tool fails in ArcObjects depending on output location?

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.2

The code I am writing for a button (ArcObjects 9.2, Visual Studio 2005) takes the attributes for selected points in a shapefile and writes them to a table:

```
Dim pGp As GeoProcessor = New GeoProcessor
pGp.OverwriteOutput = True
Dim pParams As IVariantArray = New VarArrayClass
...
Dim strFolderName As String = "C:\temp"
Dim strTableName As String = "TandE_data2.dbf"
With pParams
    .RemoveAll()
    .Add(pTELayer) 'A point SHP with at least one feature selected
    .Add(strFolderName) '("in_memory")
    .Add(strTableName) '("TandE_data2")
End With
pGp.Execute("TableToTable_conversion", pParams, Nothing)
```

As written, the process will fail at the pGp.Execute statement on the third execution, with the message

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in SDtools.dll
```

appearing in Visual Studio's output window. If the output is directed to an in_memory workspace table instead of a DBF (using the values seen in the code comments), the code always runs to completion.

What changes do I need to make to the code for it to output to a DBF consistantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that using TableToDBASE instead of TableToTable doesn't cause the same error. I had to jump through a couple of extra hoops to get the table named right, but now I can run the code at least 10 times without getting an error.